# Need to rename all Json keys of json file in php

Tags: php, json, sorting, key, rename

I need to rename all Keys of the json file in php.

**Json File : construction.php**

```
{
  "result": {
    "UK": [
      {
        "name": "Leo Philips",
        "age": "28",
        "category": "Senior",
        "place": "London",
        "experience_yrs": "4"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mc Roy",
        "age": "25",
        "category": "Junior",
        "place": "London",
        "experience_yrs": "1"
      }
    ],
    "Europe": [
      {
        "name": "Reo Thomas",
        "age": "31",
        "category": "Senior",
        "place": "Paris",
        "experience_yrs": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to rename all keys

"name" to NA,
"age" to AG,
"category" to CA,
"place" to PL,
"experience_yrs" to EY

**Need Following output in fullconstruction.php**

```
{
  "result": {
    "UK": [
      {
        "NM": "Leo Philips",
        "AG": "28",
        "CA": "Senior",
        "PL": "London",
        "EY": "4"
      },
      {
        "NM": "Mc Roy",
        "AG": "25",
        "CA": "Junior",
        "PL": "London",
        "EY": "1"
      }
    ],
    "Europe": [
      {
        "NM": "Reo Thomas",
        "AG": "31",
        "CA": "Senior",
        "PL": "Paris",
        "EY": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**This is the code I used in fullconstruction.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$parsed = json_decode(file_get_contents("construction.php"), true);
$result = [];
if($parsed['Success']){
    foreach($parsed['result'] as $val){
        $result[] = [
            "NM"=> $val['name'],
            "AG"=> $val['age'],
            "CA"=> $val['category'],
            "PL"=> $val['place'],
            "EY"=> $val['experience_yrs']
         ];
    }     // or what you want.

}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Getting blank [].

How it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working in my side,

Please try with below code it works correctly.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$parsed = json_decode(file_get_contents("construction.php"), true);
$result = [];
if($parsed['result']){
    foreach($parsed['result'] as $key => $val){
       foreach($val as $final_val){
        $result[$key][] = [
            "NM"=> $final_val['name'],
            "AG"=> $final_val['age'],
            "CA"=> $final_val['category'],
            "PL"=> $final_val['place'],
            "EY"=> $final_val['experience_yrs']
         ];
        }
    }     // or what you want.

}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**Output**

```
{"UK":[{"NM":"Leo Philips","AG":"28","CA":"Senior","PL":"London","EY":"4"},
{"NM":"Mc Roy","AG":"25","CA":"Junior","PL":"London","EY":"1"}],"Europe":
[{"NM":"Reo Thomas","AG":"31","CA":"Senior","PL":"Paris","EY":"6"}]}
```

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop **twice**

Use below code.

```
$json = '{
  "result": {
    "UK": [
      {
        "name": "Leo Philips",
        "age": "28",
        "category": "Senior",
        "place": "London",
        "experience_yrs": "4"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mc Roy",
        "age": "25",
        "category": "Junior",
        "place": "London",
        "experience_yrs": "1"
      }
    ],
    "Europe": [
      {
        "name": "Reo Thomas",
        "age": "31",
        "category": "Senior",
        "place": "Paris",
        "experience_yrs": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}';

$parsed = json_decode($json, true);

//print_r($parsed);


foreach($parsed['result'] as $key => $val){

   if($parsed['result'][$key]){
       $subdata = $parsed['result'][$key];
       foreach($subdata as $k1 => $v1){

            $parsed['result'][$key][$k1] = [
                "NM"=> $v1['name'],
                "AG"=> $v1['age'],
                "CA"=> $v1['category'],
                "PL"=> $v1['place'],
                "EY"=> $v1['experience_yrs']
             ];


       }
   }

}

echo json_encode($parsed);
```

**Here you will get**

```
{
  "result": {
    "UK": [
      {
        "NM": "Leo Philips",
        "AG": "28",
        "CA": "Senior",
        "PL": "London",
        "EY": "4"
      },
      {
        "NM": "Mc Roy",
        "AG": "25",
        "CA": "Junior",
        "PL": "London",
        "EY": "1"
      }
    ],
    "Europe": [
      {
        "NM": "Reo Thomas",
        "AG": "31",
        "CA": "Senior",
        "PL": "Paris",
        "EY": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```